# Java JaCoCo integration report in multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, testing, report, jacoco

My project has the following structure as shown below. My integration tests are in module A and it uses classes in other modules. I want JaCoCo to include the code-coverage of the other modules that are executed by module A.

I understand that the plugin can merge reports of other modules, but this is an different scenario. I'm executing the integration-test on module A

```
pom.xml
|
|
-----sub module A - application layer - executable integration-test with submodule B & C
|
|
-----sub module B - business logic - has no integration test
|
|
-----sub module C - business logic - has no integration test
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and used jacoco-aggragete execution. I guess, there are many solution but I will try to tell most suitable for your problem. You should add jacoco plugin to pom.xml into root directory.

And this plugin should have 2 different specify execution: first one jacoco-initialize, second one jacoco-report. After that, I think you can module-A such as reporter module. Reporter module's pom has again jacoco plugin but it has different execution. That execution is jacoco-site-aggregate. This execution calculate the all report aggregating with depends on module.

Your root pom.xml should have this;

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-report</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Your module-A's pom.xml should have this;

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>Module-B</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>Module-C</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-site-aggregate</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And please run maven command

```
mvn clean verify
```

Now, merged reports should be in your module-A>target>site>jacoco-aggregate.

I hope, this answer can help you for this problem. Maybe this article can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by adding the following property each module:

```xml
<propertie>
  <sonar.sources>target/generated-sources/java</sonar.sources>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to fix this by a maven plugin which is close to Jacoco's one (same goal) but read Maven's reactor to collect dependencies. This avoids the creation of a dedicated module that declares the dependencies as suggested above and recommanded for Sonar Scanner. If you're still struggling on that problem, have a look at it : https://github.com/codefilarete/jacoco-aggregate-submodule.
Note that the feature has already been raised at Jacoco without answer : https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1241